# Python dunder method for `is`

Tags: python

While looking through the docs, and specifically here http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#is, I still can't find the dunder/protocol method that defines the implementation of the Python keyword `is`. What method determines it? From what I understand, all `is` does is to compare the results of the `id` function when called on two objects.

Comment: You are right; and `id` returns the memory location of the object. So unless you want to put your object in some specific location in RAM, you should never need to write your own `is` implementation. If you want to check for equivalence of two objects, use `__eq__` instead

Comment: I just learned the meaning of [dunder](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DunderAlias)!

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Ha, upvote the thread to show appreciate :p

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: That's a little misleading, because it's only true for CPython. Jython or PyPy couldn't return a memory location even if they wanted to.

Comment: @abarnert: fair enough. I /was/ just referring to CPython - I should have made that clear

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no dunder method for `is`. You can't override it, and that's intentional. The whole point of `is` is that it tells you whether two expressions reference the same value. So it has to be false, by definition, for two different values. So there's no need to override it.

As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is) put it:

> The operators `is` and `not is` test for object identity: `x is y` is true if and only if *x* and *y* are the same object.

(There's a little more in the [Data model docs](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types).)

---

Also, `is` doesn't compare the results of `id`.

[`id`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) is just defined to return "an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime". Which means `is` certainly *could* use `id`, but I don't know of any implementation where it does.

That being said, in CPython, it does effectively the same thing under the covers—[`is`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Python/ceval.c#l4430) checks that the pointers are equal, while [`id`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Python/bltinmodule.c#l964) casts the pointer into an integer and returns it. So the only difference between implementing it directly vs. implementing it via `id` would be an extra pair of function calls and a cast that would compile to no machine code…

But in other implementations, even that may not be true. (Which should be obvious, when you consider that Jython and PyPy are written in languages that don't even have such a thing as a pointer.) For example, in PyPy, `is` checks that the underlying RPython objects are the same, while `id` returns a key generated on the fly (and cached if you later call `id` on the same value).

Comment: Wait, so there is no pure python implementation for `is`, its all in C?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian: It's all in C in CPython. Of course it's in Java, .NET, or RPython in other Python implementations.

Comment: Regardless of implementation, `id(a) == id(b)` *must* return the same result as `a is b`... would you agree?

Comment: Nope. If `a` dies before `b` is created, they may have the same id despite being different objects. This isn't possible with `is`, since both objects must survive until the operator is evaluated.

Comment: @user2357112 Provided that `a` dies, I assume that means its gced, then how could `id` return anything at all for it?

Comment: It can be collected between the evaluation of its ID and the creation of `b`. Consider the call `id([]) == id([])` (which returned `True` when I just tried it). The first list is created, then its ID is evaluated. At this point, there are no more references to it, and it can be GC'd. Then the second list is created, and it's free to reuse the just-collected object.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian: This problem can also happen if you store `id` numbers and compare then later. Correctly using `id` for anything that couldn't be done with `is` can be tricky; you have to ensure that you only ever compare `id` numbers of objects with overlapping lifetimes.

Comment: @user2357112 For both expressions, it's equally impossible for `a` and `b` to be garbage collected during their evaluations. In order to be bit by garbage collection, you would need to write `ida = id(a)` followed sometime later by `idb = id(b)`, and *then* evaluate `ida == idb`... but that's not what I asked ;)

Comment: @nmclean: If `a` and `b` are variables, they won't be collected, but if they're placeholders for arbitrary expressions, `a` may be collectable after `id(a)` is evaluated. Try `id([]) == id([])` and see what you get.

Comment: @user2357112: Of course the fun thing is that Python doesn't _guarantee_ that they'll be collected as soon as they can be, or that the memory will be reused, or that the `id` has anything to do with the memory location. In CPython, this will almost always be `True` because the GC works by refcounting, `id` is memory, and the allocator tries to reuse recently released memory whenever possible; in most other implementations it will almost always be `False` because the GC won't free the value immediately, and `id` values are not based on memory and aren't reused as quickly.

Comment: @user2357112 I understand that (and it's interesting, since I wouldn't have expected the `[]` to actually be gc'd that quickly), but it muddles up the essence of my point which is that an *id comparison gives you the same answer as `is` with the same two parameters*. Consider that `(id([]) == id([])) == ([] is [])` would be an invalid test because it involves *four* different parameters, not two.

Comment: "With the same two parameters" - that assumes that you're performing both tests, rather than replacing an `is` test with an `id` comparison. To perform both comparisons, you need to make guarantees about object lifetime that don't exist if you replace `is` with `id`. It seems much more likely that you'd be interested in replacing one test with the other.

Comment: @nmclean: In CPython, the GC works by refcounting, so unless you have a reference cycle (which you obviously don't for an empty list display), objects almost always get cleaned up immediately. That's not true for the other implementations—but the values _could_ still get cleaned up in the middle of the expression, so if you write code that assumes they never will, your code is still wrong in PyPy/etc. Anyway, the key point is that `[] is []` requires both values to be alive simultaneously, until the `is` finishes, while `id([]) == id([])` does not.

Comment: While we're at it, it's also worth noting that `id` is a regular function in `builtins`, while `is` is a built-in operator. Besides the almost-certainly-irrelevant fact that looking up `id` and calling it twice and then calling `int.__eq__` is going to be slower, there's also the potentially-critical fact that `id` can easily be shadowed by a global or local (or even monkeypatched in `builtins`)…